# Showing the set S = {$\ x^4{,}\ x^3\left|x\right|$} as Linearly Independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is my question, i understand that if we take two cases separately, namely

1.) $[0,\infty \ )$

2.) $(-\infty \,0  ]$

This is due to the presence of Modulus, so in the first case we will have $[\ x^4{,}\ x^4]$ which we can clearly tell it is linearly Dependent and In the 2nd case we will have $[\ x^4{,}-\ x^4]$ which is nothing but the scalar multiple of the other element, so again we have it as Linearly Dependent. The Confusing part for me is when we consider $x\in \ R\ $, in my mind I'm simply thinking of $\left(-\infty {,}\ \infty \ \right)$ but it is not linearly dependent as i expected but rather Linearly Independent. I'm not able to understand how is that happening, Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you consider the graph of the functions?

Comment: Here's the way to understand what's going on. On one interval you have a constant $c$ so that $f_1=cf_2$. On the other interval, you have a constant $c'$ so that $f_1=c'f_2$. Since $c\ne c'$, there is no constant that works on all of $\Bbb R$, and so the two functions are linearly independent as functions on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @TedShifrin That makes complete sense now!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\{x^3|x|,x^4\}$ were dependent.

Now, there exist $a_1,a_2$ such that $$a_1x^3|x|+a_2x^4=0$$ and for some $i,$ $a_i\neq 0.$ Since if $a_1=0$ implies $a_2=0$ and vice versa, we may say that $a_1, a_2\neq 0.$ Thus, we may write

$$f(x)=-\frac{a_2x}{a_1}=|x|.$$

Now, $|x|=|-x|$ but $f(x)\neq f(-x),$ a contradiction. Hence we have that our set must be linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The thing is, the number of elements you have considered is three, whereas the question stated 2 elements, ${x^4{,}\ x^3\left|x\right|}$ here, $x^3$ is being multiplied with $\left|x\right|$

Comment: but I'll assume that we can show in the same way as $a_1x^4 + a_2x^3|x| = 0$ and solve in the same manner! thank you!!! :)

Comment: So sorry for the confusion! I have corrected the answer, and yes you may solve it in a similar manner!

Comment: Thank youuuu!!!